# Overflowed content is showing on focus

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a set of items in flex container. Only a certain number of items are visible at the same time. The rest are hidden in the overflow the parent. I can shift the flex container element left/right to show/hide different items. The problem I'm having is that if you tab through the items (i.e. using the "tab" key on the keyboard), the flex container sort of shifts itself so that the focused item is made visible. This happens even though the `left` position of the flex container is fixed. What's even stranger is if you change the left position after the flex container has "shifted" because of the tab focus, it stays offset by whatever amount it shifted itself by.

I have an example below. You'll see that only items 2,3,4 are visible. But if you tab through the items, item #5 will be come visible, then #6, etc. This doesn't happen in reverse though (item #1 never becomes visible even though it becomes focused).

I was thinking maybe the flex container is scrolling, so I tried setting `overflow: hidden` on the flex container (not just on the container's parent). That didn't fix it.

Any ideas for how to prevent the flex container from shifting as its children come into focus?

This happens in Chrome and Firefox.

I can't disable focus on the items because I want it to be accessible.

EDIT: As ZohirSalak notes below, the issue is that one of the elements scrolls as you tab through the items. What's weird is that it's the `.track-outer` element, not `.track-inner`. It seems strange that setting the width of `.track-outer` and setting overflow to hidden, it can still scroll. And there's no scrollbar and you can't use a scroll wheel to scroll it.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.track-outer {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
}

.track-inner {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: -160px;
}
```

```html
<div class='track-outer'>
  <div class='track-inner'>
    <a href='#one'>item one</a>
    <a href='#two'>item two</a>
    <a href='#three'>item three</a>
    <a href='#four'>item four</a>
    <a href='#five'>item five</a>
    <a href='#six'>item six</a>
    <a href='#seven'>item seven</a>
    <a href='#eight'>item eight</a>
    <a href='#nine'>item nine</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you use `tab key` to jump between elements, it's the scroll that's moving nothing to do with `left` property, The element start with `left:-160px` that's where it goes back to, This is not an optimal way of implementing custom scroll behavior

Comment: @ZohirSalak I'm not really trying to implement scrolling per se. Is there a way to turn scrolling off for the flex container? I thought that setting `overflow: hidden` would do that, but apparently not.

Comment: You can disable tabbing using `tabindex="-1"` on all `<a>` elements, other than that i'm not really sure

Comment: @ZohirSalak Yeah, I mentioned that in the post. I can't do it because it wouldn't be accessible. Thanks for taking a look, though!

Comment: I assume your using Js to move the items around, when you do you can give the hidden elements `-1` and the other ones normal tab index order

Comment: @ZohirSalak I would still need the hidden items to be tab-able, since someone using a screenreader (vision impaired or blind) wouldn't need to see them anyway and being able to focus them would allow the items to be clicked/selected.

Comment: No difference between a screen reader and a normal user, they both won't be able to see the hidden elements, I assume you have some contraption else where that would allow the rest of the elements to show up when needed, Essentially the elements aren't there until needed, Like an Ajax call, otherwise why hide them in first place

Comment: @ZohirSalak Yeah, it's part of a larger set of components. This is just a very simplified example that shows the issue. Though all of the elements will already exist in the component when the page loads; they won't be dynamically loaded. A screenreader will read anything that you can tab to, even if it's off the edge of the screen. I just tested to confirm. You might be thinking of `display: none`; a screenreader won't read something "hidden" in that way.

Comment: You write: "I can't disable focus on the items because I want it to be accessible." And there's your answer why it *shouldn't* be that way: "Accessible" also means that it must be possible to navigate to all elements *using a keyboard* (not a mouse or similar device), mostly with the TAB key which focusses the selected elements. I am talking about people who *don't*  have visual problems, but who for example can't handle a mouse, so they need to navigate with the keyboard (or even a special keyboard). But they still *see* (and *read*)  the content, so it must be visible when focused that way.

Comment: @Johannes That's a good point. I'll have to rethink that part.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution. You basically listen for the scroll event on `.track-outer` and set its scroll to zero. You don't need to throttle the scroll event because it seems to only be possible to trigger it by tabbing. Maybe not ideal, but it seems to work.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.track-outer')
el.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  el.scrollLeft = 0
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.track-outer {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
}

.track-inner {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: -160px;
}
```

```html
<div class='track-outer'>
  <div class='track-inner'>
    <a href='#one'>item one</a>
    <a href='#two'>item two</a>
    <a href='#three'>item three</a>
    <a href='#four'>item four</a>
    <a href='#five'>item five</a>
    <a href='#six'>item six</a>
    <a href='#seven'>item seven</a>
    <a href='#eight'>item eight</a>
    <a href='#nine'>item nine</a>
  </div>
</div>
```